# How can I run my own method in every pymodbus server transaction that is processed

Tags: pymodbus

I would like to run my own method whenever in a pymodbus server whenever a message is processed. Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While running through the examples, I came across an example where they subclass `pymodbus.datastore.ModbusSparseDataBlock` https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/callback_server.html

The example probably implements more than you'd need, at minimum you should just override:

- `__init__`: by passing the a `dict` of values, it provides the server with the legal address range a client can request
- `setValues`: this is where the magic happens: here you can add your own callbacks to any incoming `values` for a given `address`.

My minimal example looks like this:

```py
import logging                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                
from pymodbus.datastore import (                                                                                                                                                
    ModbusServerContext,                                                                                                                                                        
    ModbusSlaveContext,                                                                                                                                                         
    ModbusSparseDataBlock,                                                                                                                                                      
)                                                                                                                                                                               
from pymodbus.server.sync import StartSerialServer                                                                                                                              
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
class CallbackDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):                                                                                                                                 
    """callbacks on operation"""                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                         
        super().__init__({k: k for k in range(60)})                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                
    def setValues(self, address, value):                                                                                                                                        
        logger.info(f"Got {value} for {address}")                                                                                                                               
        super().setValues(address, value)                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
def run_server():                                                                                                                                                               
    block = CallbackDataBlock()                                                                                                                                                 
    store = ModbusSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block)                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)                                                                                                                    
    StartSerialServer(                                                                                                                                                          
        context,                                                                                                                                                                
        framer=ModbusRtuFramer,                                                                                                                                                 
        port="/dev/ttyNS0",                                                                                                                                                     
        timeout=0.005,                                                                                                                                                          
        baudrate=19200,                                                                                                                                                         
    )                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                      
    run_server()
```